# Internet Explorer 8 break function

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, internet-explorer-8, break

I'm using AngularsJS 1.1.3 with Internet Explorer 8.

In my code with a forloop which iterate through a high number items of an array, I have this error:

> Stop running this script? A script on this page is causing internet
>   explorer to run slowly...?

I made a search on Internet and I found that I need to break the forloop cycle in many pieces. 
I'm looking for a method which make a break (for example every 10 loops) , 
for who will suggest the `setTimeout` function, this one wait for some time before executing the function passed as argument, what I need is making a break, while looping inside the forloop iteration and then continue executing the forloop.

I added a screenshot for the error.

[image]

I found this function :

```
$scope.sleep=function(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And within my Forloop I added an If condition:

```
for(var i=0 ; i<tab.length ; i++)    //tab has more than 50 elements
{
   price=price+ tab[i];
   total=total +tab[i].unitprice ;
   if(i % 10 ==0 ) sleep(2000);
}
```

The problem with this code is that when the if evaluated a true an the sleep method is called, after that the excution doesn't go through the other items but leave the forloop, and I don't know why.

Comment: can you console.log the counter, the no of times the for loop is getting executed, that might give you some idea of why page is getting unresponsive

Comment: hi, i made 30 iterations  with a simple calcul

Comment: I solved the problem implementing a pagination directive ,using the sleep method above wasn't a good idea.